# Android : How do I return the item as a char not an object from a custom gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I am developing a hangman game for android, I am struggling with setting the gameplay rules for the onclick listener as gridview.getItem returns an object not a char value.

custom grid view

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private String[] items;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
    }
    Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);

// text is set on button through a string array
    button.setText(items[position]);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ArrayAdapter<Character>` instead of BaseAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your code as here

```
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the BaseAdapter by changing the getItem as

```
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
  return items[position];
 }

Or you can use an ArrayAdapter
```

Answer (score 0):

If your items are strings then why not do:

```
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {

    return items[position];

}
```

I might be wrong with this I'm new at android programming